# How do I sum two cells only if they both have a value

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use the SUM function to subtract two cells, but I only want it to do so if both cells have a number each.

Right now if there isn't a number in the second cell it gives a (wrong) result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little confused by your explanation. You want to use the SUM function to subtract? If you just want to sum two cells only if they both have a numerical value you can use the function

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),ISNUMBER(B1)),SUM(A1,B1),"")
```

Replace A1 and B1 with the two cells you want to add. This formula first tests that they are both numbers, and if that is the case, it will sum them. If false, it will leave the cell blank.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you want is

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),ISNUMBER(B1)),A1-B1,"")
```

It will remain empty till both number are filled.

Or you can make your calculations manual then it will not calculate till you hit F9 and you can just use the standard `=A1-B1` and the value will nto change till you force the calculations.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes,I am trying to subtract two cells but only if there is a number in both cells, otherwise I'd like it to stay blank. Is there something wrong with using sum to subtract? I'm not familiar with excel and thank you again for your help.

Comment: @user6581745 When using SUM() to subtract you would need to make the second one negative.  So `SUM(A1,-B1)` as compared to only typing `A1-B1`.  It is a lot of extra work to get the same answer.  I only use SUM() when it is a range of cells or an array of values.  If it is only two cells then I always split it out.  Less typing.  BTW.  If this answered your question please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.